# How can i rewire the language url in mahgento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, frontend, multistore

How Can i Rewrite the Language Switcher URL in magneto 2
i used that language switcher in that the URL with

> "___store=fr&___from_store=en"

so how can i rewire for all place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way is to rewrite the store codes to the URL

Store->Configuration->General->Web->Url Options